# Errorres caractéres especiales con Python en Codeacademy

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error aparece siempre que utilizo caractéres como tílde "´" o "ñ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente es un error. Se debe a la codificación que usa ese sitio que no permite los caracteres acentuados y la `ñ`.

Para solucionarlo, cuando necesites incluir estos caracteres en la consola de ejercicios agrega una `u` antes de las comillas. De la siguiente forma:

```
print u"StackOverflow en español!"
```

La `u` antes de cualquier cadena de texto le hace saber a Python que debe tratar el texto siguiente **como una cadena Unicode**, por lo que podemos evitar los problemas con código, documentos o sitios que no están preparados para la internacionalización o ***i18n***.

Para evitar este error **en tus propios scripts** debes añadir como primera o segunda línea la codificación que usa tu archivo. Los sistemas más modernos aceptan la codificación UTF-8, por lo que tus scripts se verían así:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

La definición de la codificación en Python se encuentra en el [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

> ### Nota
>
> Dado que no tienes control sobre el código fuente de CodeAcademy, **siempre** debes indicarle cuando tu texto necesite ser tratado como UTF-8. Adicionalmente, te recomiendo que levantes un reporte en su sitio de soporte: https://help.codecademy.com/hc/en-us?utm_source=Forum_on-platform_FTUE&utm_medium=homepage_banner

Comment: Hay una forma de configurarlo para no tener que colocar la "u" siempre? si hay muchos print es una tarea tediosa

Comment: No se puede @PupoXws, es muy recomendable que __siempre__ indiques la codificación en tus scripts, pero en los ajenos, no tienes muchas alternativas. Actualicé mi respuesta para aclarar este punto.